# What is the fastest way to add new column based on dataframe entries in specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

So I have this dataframe

```
#   Name Comp1 Con2 Vis3 Tra4 Pred5 Adap6
# 1   A1     x <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 2   A2  <NA>    x <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 3   B1  <NA> <NA>    x <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 4   B2  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     x  <NA>
# 5   B3  <NA> <NA> <NA>    x  <NA>  <NA>
# 6   D2  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>     x
# 7   F6  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     x  <NA>
```

I want to add a column to databackend that displays a value from 1 to 6 based on which column the "x" is on databackend. So the additional column would look like this

```
#   Name Comp1 Con2 Vis3 Tra4 Pred5 Adap6 stage
# 1   A1     x <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     1
# 2   A2  <NA>    x <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     2
# 3   B1  <NA> <NA>    x <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     3
# 4   B2  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     x  <NA>     5
# 5   B3  <NA> <NA> <NA>    x  <NA>  <NA>     4
# 6   D2  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>     x     6
# 7   F6  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     x  <NA>     5
```

since my dataframe is very large in the original script, I am looking for the fastest (automatic) way to do this. I´ve tried using the for loop but it takes too long.

### data

```
databackend <- structure(list(Name = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "B3", "D2", "F6"
), Comp1 = c("x", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Con2 = c(NA, "x", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Vis3 = c(NA, NA, "x", NA, NA, NA, NA), Tra4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "x", NA, NA), Pred5 = c(NA, NA, NA, "x", NA, NA, 
"x"), Adap6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "x", NA), stage = c(1, 2, 
3, 5, 4, 6, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In the column `Pred5` NA is located in the 4th row and the 7th row, not the 4th and the 6th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do (assuming as in your example a single "x" in every row):

```
max.col(!is.na(databackend[-1]))

[1] 1 2 3 5 4 6 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Relatively simple

```
> tmp=which(databackend[,-1]=="x",arr.ind=T)
> tmp[order(tmp[,"row"]),"col"]
[1] 1 2 3 5 4 6 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `which` and `apply`:

```r
apply(databackend[-1], 1, \(x) which(x == "x"))
#[1] 1 2 3 5 4 6 5
```

---

A benchmark, `max.col` is the fastest:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  apply = apply(databackend[-1], 1, \(x) which(x == "x")),
  which = {tmp=which(databackend[,-1]=="x",arr.ind=T)
  tmp[order(tmp[,"row"]),"col"]},
  max.col = max.col(!is.na(databackend[-1]))
)

Unit: microseconds
    expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
   apply 149.4 165.95 232.308 196.20 216.95 2882.4   100
   which 118.9 144.35 184.684 158.10 190.45  907.0   100
 max.col  51.5  73.00  88.302  79.45  94.40  326.1   100
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
> rowSums(col(databackend[-1])*(!is.na(databackend[-1])))
[1] 1 2 3 5 4 6 5
```